# Only get the number from parent id

Tags: javascript, jquery, attr, parseint

I want to get the `id` from the parent element of a button, and the cut the text of. My guess was this:

**HTML**

```
<div id="test_4">
    <button id="button">Get ID</button>
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$('#button').click(function() {
    parentID = $(this).parent().attr('id');
    newID = parseInt(parentID);

    alert(newID);
});
```

But that outputs `NaN`.

What is the right way to do this?
[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3FZya/)

Comment: please provide your html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('#button').click(function() {

    parentID = $(this).parent().attr('id');
    newID = +(parentID.match(/\d+/));

    alert(newID);
});
```

[**JSFiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/JamesD/3FZya/1/).

Comment: Hi James, just out of curiousity, what if the id had a value like `<div id="782test_4">` and would only want to return the digits `7824`, what's the Regex match?

Answer (score 4):

There are many answers which use Regular Expressions but I don't [recommend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454) [it](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/06/regular-expressions-now-you-have-two-problems.html). What you need is `data-` attributes. You use jQuery already so you can access your `id` with [`.data()`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/) method. Here is an example;

**HTML**

```
<div id="test_4" data-id="4">
<!--            ^^^^^^^^^^^^ this has to be added to use .data() -->
    <button id="button">Get ID</button>
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$('#button').click(function() {
    var newID = $(this).parent().data('id');
    alert(newID);
});
```

Comment: This outputs 'undefined' and not 4?

Comment: Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/karalamalar/d2qZL/). What browser do you use? BTW you have to add `data-id` to your mark-up in case you missed it.

Answer (score 1):

Use a simple regex

```
$('#button').click(function () {

    var parentID = $(this).parent().attr('id');
    var newID = parentID.match(/\d+$/)[0];

    alert(newID);
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/CgtCc/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex to match the number inside your `id` string:

```
parentID = $(this).parent().attr('id').match(/\d+/);
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/3FZya/3/)**

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$('#button').click(function() {

    parentID = $(this).parent().attr('id');

    newID = parseInt(parentID.split("_")[1]);

    alert(newID);
});
```

Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/3FZya/6/

Answer (score -2):

```
$('#button').click(function() {

    parentID = $(this).parent().attr("id");
    newID = parentID;

    alert(newID);
});
```

this will work

Comment: This not awnsers my question :)